# How to setup logging when starting elasticsearch in embedded mode

Tags: java, elasticsearch, log4j

For testing purposes, I'm using ElasticSearch in "embedded mode", i. e. I'm writing Java code and start the ES node via `org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder`. As it seems, there is no such comfort as of having a (yaml-)configuration layer on top of log4j as it is the case for the command-line setup just out of the box.

But instead of keeping two separate configurations in sync to configure log4j, I'd like to use the existing `logging.yml` file in my embedded-world also.

Is there a simple way to extract the logging-setup out of the command-line-setup-code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I realise my answer doesn't cater for the precise requirements of the question, but it might be useful for someone else who has the higher level problem in the title of this question and different detailed requirements.)

The other likely scenario for wanting to configure Elasticsearch logging when the Elasticsearch node is embedded is when you want it to use the existing logging framework of the program you're embedding it into.

If you are using log4j as your logging framework and want an Elasticsearch node embedded into the same program to log via your log4j then try something like this:

```
     ESLoggerFactory.setDefaultFactory(new Log4jESLoggerFactory());
     Node node = NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder()
             .settings(mySettings).client(true)
             .clusterName(elasticSearchClusterName).node();
```

This assumes you've already set up your own log4j logger.  (And obviously the exact details of building the node will vary, but the key thing is to call `ESLoggerFactory.setDefaultFactory` before building it.)

The extra imports you need for this are:

```
import org.elasticsearch.common.logging.ESLoggerFactory;
import org.elasticsearch.common.logging.log4j.Log4jESLoggerFactory;
```

Note that Elasticsearch will log using your log4j's root logger, so the logging level is set for your root logger is the level the Elasticsearch classes will log at.

Answer (score 0):

After looking into the actual ES code that bootstraps the system on command-line startup, I came up with the following workaround:

```
final NodeBuilder nodeBuilder = new NodeBuilder();
Settings settings = InternalSettingsPreparer.prepareSettings(ImmutableSettings.Builder.EMPTY_SETTINGS, true).v1();
LogConfigurator.configure(settings);
node = nodeBuilder.build();
client = node.client();
```

Assuming me getting things right, this basically parses the configuration files an extra time and passes the so retrieved `org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings` to the `LogConfigurator`.

Notice, that this has to be done before `NodeBuilder.build` is called.